# Use asp.net label for a css class name

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to use a label value for a css class name.

I am getting a label value from database through Eval and want to use it for a css class name

Here is what I am doing

```
<span class="<asp:Label ID="lbl_icon" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("icon")%>'></asp:Label>"></span>
```

but I'm not getting the result which i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any need to use a Label control there. You could just try the following:

```
<span class='<%# Eval("icon")%>'></span>
```

Comment: Can i use label by the way ? Or if I can so how ?

Comment: @SaadSuri without being sure 100%, I think that you can't.

Comment: @SaadSuri - The Label control being rendered as a span element, you would end up with something like: `<span class="<span>value</span>" ...></span>`. It may work with a Literal control however, since it renders only its content (although Christos' answer is simpler). On the other hand, you could use a Label as your span element, setting its `CssClassName` with the `Eval("icon")` value.